# Formatting DateInterval with huge seconds value

Tags: php, dateinterval

Recently I ran into a simple `DateInterval` issue. The class does not re-calculate its properties after I created the `DateInterval` object with a huge seconds value as follow:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('PT6685071S');
echo $interval->format("%m months %d days %H hours %i minutes %s seconds");
```

The output becomes:

> 0 months 0 days 00 hours 0 minutes 6685071 seconds

How to make it display like:

> 2 months 16 days 8 hours 57 minutes 51 seconds

without dividing seconds by 60, minutes by 60, etc ?

*( hope my calculation is correct )*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved with DateTime class

Use:

```
echo secondsToTime(1640467);
```

18 days, 23 hours, 41 minutes and 7 seconds

## Function:

```
function secondsToTime($seconds) {
    $dtF = new DateTime("@0");
    $dtT = new DateTime("@$seconds");
    return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
}
```

[sample demo](https://eval.in/296299)